# Username auto fill in Login Page after Register success (Redirect to Login) in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I redirected to my login page after register for success. In fact, how can I carry my registered username when I redirect to the login page and show it in the Login page username input.

**My controller**

```
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Register(Account account)
        {
            if (!db.Accounts.Any(x => x.Username.Equals(account.Username)))
            {
                Account acc = new Account()
                {
                    Username = account.Username,
                    Password = account.Password,
                    CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    IsDeleted = false,
                };
                db.Accounts.Add(acc);
                db.SaveChanges();

                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(acc.AccountID.ToString(), false);
                ViewBag.Success = "User registered. You may login now!";
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Error = "User already exist!";
                return View();
            }
        }
```

**Login Username Input**

```
<input type="text" name="Username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
```

Comment: It may not be safe to fill the password on the login page. you can do login work (create a ticket or some else) after register and redirect to the main page.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. I only want username to fill on the login page. I'll try to create a ticket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create an overload for Login.

```
public ActionResult Login(string userName)
{
   return View();
}

 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Register(Account account)
 {
   ...
   return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account", new {userName=account.Username});               

 }
```

EDIT: To hide username value you could apply basic base64 encoding.

```
public string Encode(string strToEncode)
{
    byte[] encodedVal = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strToEncode);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(encodedVal);
}

public string Decode(string strToDecode)
{
    byte[] decodedVal = Convert.FromBase64String(strToDecode);
    return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decodedVal);
}

public ActionResult Login(string userName)
{
   var userNameDecoded = Decode(userName);
   return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(Account account)
{
   ...
   return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account", new {userName=Encode(account.Username)});               

}
```

Comment: Thanks it works. But username can be seen in the link like this "http://localhost:52728/?username=ee". I'm fining a way to hide it.

Comment: If you don't want to show username value you should use encrypt/decrypt in query strings.

Answer (score 2):

There are two way to get the username in Login action result.

1. To pass the anonymous object in RedirectToAction.

```
    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account", new {username=account.username});
```

2. To fetch the username from FormsAuthentication ticket

```
    HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
    if (authCookie != null)
    {
        // Get the forms authentication ticket.
        FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = 
        FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
        var identity = new GenericIdentity(authTicket.Name, "Forms");
        var principal = new MyPrincipal(identity);
        // Get the custom user data encrypted in the ticket.
        string userData = ((FormsIdentity)(Context.User.Identity)).Ticket.UserData;
        // Deserialize the json data and set it on the custom principal.
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        principal.User = (User)serializer.Deserialize(userData, typeof(User));
        // Set the context user.
        Context.User = principal;
    }
```

Comment: the first way worked. But when redirect to login view, username could seen like this "http://localhost:52728/?username=ee". Is there any way to hide that?

Comment: Yes, let use tempdata in mvc to pass data from controller to controller.
```
TempData["username"]=account.Username;
return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
```
and in login method
```
var username= TempData.Peek("username");
```

Answer (score 2):

Here two ways commonly used for send data form one controller to another controller

1. You can pass data `return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account", new {userName=account.Username});` and get it

   public ActionResult Login(string userName)
   {
      return View();
   }
2. Or You can simply use tempdata

Set ==>
`TempData["UserName"] = account.Username;`

Get ==> `var userName = TempData["UserName"].ToString();`

Answer (score 0):

First when you redirect to login action pass username to it and receive username in login action then store the username in viewBag. On view set text value using viewBag

```
public ActionResult Login(string UserName)
        {
            ViewBag.UserName=username; 
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Register(Account account)
        {
            if (!db.Accounts.Any(x => x.Username.Equals(account.Username)))
            {
                Account acc = new Account()
                {
                    Username = account.Username,
                    Password = account.Password,
                    CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    IsDeleted = false,
                };
                db.Accounts.Add(acc);
                db.SaveChanges();

                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(acc.AccountID.ToString(), false);
                ViewBag.Success = "User registered. You may login now!";
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account",account.Username);
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Error = "User already exist!";
                return View();
            }
        }
```

On View

```
<input type="text" name="Username" class="form-control" value="@ViewBag.UserName" placeholder="Username">
```

Comment: Passing parameter from Register is fine. But When it reach to login view, parameter is null.

Comment: on login view bind the data from ViewBag